# Different behavior with running psexec from WPF app when executing from command line vs. double-click

Tags: c#, wpf, process, cmd, psexec

I am using process.Start to execute psexec which executes an msi remotely.

For some reason, process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() hangs when I double-clicked on the application, but when I execute the WPF app from a command prompt it is fine.

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running your app as an administrator?  If not, it won't be able to execute an MSI.

Comment: Yes. The msiexec runs fine and exits, but psexec is hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are blocking on the synchronous ReadToEnd call.  You might want to use Process.BeginOutputReadLine instead because it's asynchronous:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx

Comment: No success meaning even the async call hangs?  Or meaning it doesn't read any data?

Comment: Reads data, but process still hangs.